# Are Turing release chunks backward compatible?

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to understand the concept of release chunks from the release matrix page: [link](http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/)

Looking at the [ESB480 build instructions](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Building+from+Source), the wording suggests that the release chunks are NOT backward compatible.

> To determine which chunk to use for a specific product version, see
>   the Release Matrix

**Question**: Are turing release chunks backward compatible?  For example, would API Manager 1.5.0 that was released with chunk 2 also run on chunk 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turing platform is a new platform release concept introduced recently. The mail thread ["Introducing the Carbon Platform Release Concept"](http://wso2.com/mailarchive/dev/2013-September/023476.html) on dev and architecture [mailing lists](http://wso2.com/mail/) explains this.

As you know, A WSO2 product = WSO2 Carbon + Set of features.

Your question is also about building from source. I know you have an idea about the [WSO2 SVN structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358459/wso2-svn-structure-documentation) and [orbit, kernel and platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861292/what-is-wso2-orbit-kernel-and-platform). You asked those questions :)

As I understand the [ESB 4.8.0 Building from Source](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Building+from+Source) wiki page suggests that you should checkout relevant chunk release tag.

The [release matrix](http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/) has the information about the each chunk for a specific product.

For example, if you want to build ESB 4.8.0, you should checkout [turing-chunk04](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk04/) tag. To build API Manager 1.5.0, you should checkout [turing-chunk02](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk02/) tag.

Since the platform has all products, you must checkout relevant tag to get the *released* product.

The backward compatibility depends on each product. For example, the ESB 4.8.0 is not directly compatible with ESB 4.7.0 as the underlying Carbon is a major upgrade and there are user management changes. In such cases you need to migrate data. However the proxies may be compatible.

In general, any turing platform product is not directly backward compatible with a previous version of product with Carbon kernel version < 4.2.0.

> Question: Are turing release chunks backward compatible? For example, would API Manager 1.5.0 that was released with chunk 2 also run on chunk 5?

AFAIU, your question is invalid. API Manager 1.5.0 is released under chunk02 and there is no API Manager release under chunk05. However API Manager 1.6.0 is released in Turing chunk 6. So you must checkout [turing-chunk06](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk06/) tag to build the API Manager 1.6.0.

I'm not sure API Manager 1.6.0 is compatible with API Manager 1.5.0. I'm not aware of the changes yet. However I can assure you that there are no changes in the user management and registry tables.

The important factors with Turing platform are that all products are based on Carbon 4.2.0 and there is only one [P2 Repository](http://wso2.com/projects/carbon/provisioning-wso2-carbon-with-equinox-p2). This means that any turing platform product can install features from a single Turing P2 repository.

I hope this helps to clear out your doubts.

Thanks!

Comment: What I was trying to understand was whether there would be any changes in Carbon Core between chunk versions.  From the mail thread and your response, it seems that Carbon Core does not break backward compatibility with chunk releases.  I.e. APIM 1.5.0 will work with Carbon Core 4.2 regardless of the chunk version of Carbon Core 4.2 you are using.  If so, this is great, my assumption [here](http://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/architecture/2014-January/014547.html) is correct, and in theory only a packaged version of each major carbon core release is required, rather than a version for each chunk.

Comment: Yes, Carbon Kernel (4.2.0) is same for all Turing platfrom chunk releases. However we cannot depend on an external Carbon kernel for a product. Even though the Carbon kernel version is same, the kernel is part of the product and it cannot be separated. Are you trying to create packages for WSO2 products? I think there should be a separate package for each product without other WSO2 dependencies. I will reply to that mail as soon as I get some time. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Isuru. I am investigating how wso2 products could be packaged, for example using debian deb package.  Ideally, one could install a product using something like `apt-get install stratos-load-balancer-4` which would first install `carbon-core-42` and then install stratos load balancer as a feature on top of carbon core 4.2.